# Windows set command

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I've been playing around with the `set /p` and the `if` commands,
but I can't figure out how to automatically let it press enter
when I type 1. Here is my code:

```
@echo off
echo 1. hello
echo 2. bye
set /p choice=Type 1 or 2. 
if %choice%==1 goto hello
if %choice%==2 goto bye
:hello
echo hello
pause
exit
:bye
echo bye
pause
exit
```

What I'm trying to do is enable my script to detect if I have pressed 1 or 2, without having to press enter.

I got the idea from an RPG batch game that also used that and I couldn't figure out where or how it was written, it was a very complex game with a lot of calls...

But please help me, I'm also trying to build an RPG with a friend of mine who is also fooling around with batch!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `choice` command along with `/C 12` for your choices.
Then, you can retrieve the user's selection from `%errorlevel%`.

Comment: Thank you, this really helped me. But how can i make `%errorlevel%` work with letters?